# How to remove console command in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I have registered EkinoNewRelic bundle and its all working however it also registers new console command called `newrelic:notify-deployment`.

How to remove this command from `app/console` without changing original code?

Comment: what do you mean by "original code"? Original code of Symfony or the bundle?

Comment: Why do you need to remove it? Is it intrusive for you because you want a clea app/console without unnecessary command?

Comment: original code that i have from EkinoNewRelicBundle which is in vendors folder. You dont ever want to modify this. I want to remove one functionality from that bundle which was added by registering this bundle. It is remove command newrelic:notify-deployment. I dont want to be ever used by my developers as we do it somewhere else.

Comment: Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can't disable it. Instead, you should override it so it would just print something like "Command disabled, use acme:notify-deployment instead." and return.

Comment: hmm interesting... you are probably right... but there must a moment when bundle is initiated and all commands are being added... if only i could overwrite this...

Comment: sure, but I'm pretty sure Symfony handles it internally and you don't want to mess with **that** :)